# HTML indenting inside PHP

Tags: php, html, indentation

I've this code:

```
<? if(is_home() || is_archive()): ?>
<ul>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url('/category/one') ?>">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url('/category/two') ?>">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url('/category/three') ?>">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<? endif ?>
```

Which produces this output:

```
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://domain/...">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://domain/...">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://domain/...">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice that `<ul>` is indented. If I use the following it outputs as expected:

```
<? if(is_home() || is_archive()): ?><ul>
...
```

I know this is trivial but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this so it still looks nice in both PHP and HMTL; I like clean output.

Comment: PHP eats up a single newline after the closing token `?>`. Why there are spaces before, no idea.

Comment: So I guess the only way is to put the opening tag on the same line or hit return twice, or am I missing something?

Comment: I feel like most things you can do to tidy up the output would mess up the actual code, which is far more important.

Comment: Personally I've given up on ironing t-shirts or caring about HTML indentation.

Comment: This question was more of a "why" and "is there a fix". The first comment seems to address this perfectly, I wasn't aware of that, I'll accept if posted as question @mario. I can figure out the alternatives now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. PHP eats up a single newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) after the closing token `?>`.
As mentioned in http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> [...] The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

One workaround is also mentioned in the comments there. If you were to add a space after the `?>`, meaning a sequence of <kbd>?</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>\n</kbd>, the newline would retain its purpose. -- But then you'd depend on another invisible character to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, why do you care if your html is formatted awkwardly?  I understand perhaps for readability purposes but there are html formatting tools available:  e.g. http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

If you're concerned about you html code being valid, try using an appropriate IDE or an html validator:  e.g.
http://validator.w3.org/

lastly, the answer to your question:
change the start of your code to this:

```
<?php if(is_home() || is_archive()){ echo "\n" ?><ul>
  <li><a href="<
...
<?php }?>
```

Comment: +1 for a valid solution but it doesn't help that much. I mean the PHP now looks uglier. I'll just leave the HTML as it is. It really doesn't matter, it was a question out of curiosity basically.

Comment: ...ok. you can have your cake, but you can't eat it too ;-)